# Prove that a set is an event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $ (X_k)_k $ be a sequence of events and define:

$ Z\left(\omega\right)=\limsup_{k\to\infty}X_{k}\left(\omega\right),\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace W\left(\omega\right)=\liminf_{k\to\infty}X_{k}\left(\omega\right) $

and:

$ Y\left(\omega\right)=\begin{cases}
\lim_{k\to\infty}X_{k}\left(\omega\right) & if\thinspace\thinspace the\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace limit\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace exist\\
0 & else
\end{cases} $

Now I want to prove that $ Y $ is a random varaible.

What Im allowed to use:

1.$ Z $ is a random variable.

2.$ W $ is a random variable.

3.An indicator of an event is a random variable.

4.A multipication of random variables is a random variable.

Now define
$ A=\left\{ Z=W\right\}  $ that is, all the $ \omega $ such that the limit exists.

If I'll manage to show thta $ A $ is an event, then I could write

$ Y=Z1_{A} $ where $ 1_A $ is the indicator of $ A $ and we're done.

I have tried something and I would like to know if its true. (Im aware that there is much simpler solution):

$ A=\left\{ \omega:Z\left(\omega\right)=W\left(\omega\right)\right\} =\left\{ \omega:\lim_{k}X_{k}\left(\omega\right)\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace exist\right\} =\left\{ \omega:X_{k}\left(\omega\right)\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace is\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace a\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace Cauchy\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace sequence\right\}  $

$ =\left\{ \omega|\forall m\in\mathbb{N},\exists N\in\mathbb{N:\forall}k_{1},k_{2}\geq N:|X_{k_{1}}\left(\omega\right)-X_{k_{2}}\left(\omega\right)<\frac{1}{m}\right\}  $

$ =\bigcap_{m\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcup_{N\in\mathbb{N}}\bigcap_{k_{1},k_{2}\geq N}\left\{ |X_{k_{1}}-X_{k_{2}}|<\frac{1}{m}\right\}  $

Since this is just a countable intersection of a countable union of a countable intersection of events, all in all $ A $ is also event.

Do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that works.  You could also use that $$A=\{\omega : Z(\omega)=W(\omega)\} = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \left\{\omega : |Z(\omega)-W(\omega)| < \frac 1n\right\}$$ for a slightly faster proof that $A$ is a countable intersection of events.